# generate unique element IDs in nested ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am facing problems generating unique IDs for nested ng-repeat blocks in angularJS. Also, I need to manage a common ngModel for all radio buttons with unique ngValues.

The basic layout is as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="folder in folders">
    <div ng-repeat="files in folder">
    ----------
    ----------
    ----------
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="folder in folder.childFolders">
           <div ng-repeat="files in folder">
                ----------
                <input type="radio" ngModel="" ngValue="">
                ----------
           </div>
           -----------
           <<This block can further nest to many levels>>
           -----------
    </div>
</div>
```

Hence, using $parent or $index is not an option here. Similarly, using radio buttons is also creating problem inside the nested block as ngModel requires a value which is common to all scopes and ngValue also needs to be unique for all radio buttons.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Search for recursive templates in AngularJS. You can solve this using ng-include.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am using recursive templates already for this. But the problem that still remains is ensuring unique values that cover all ng-repeat blocks. I want to group all radio buttons (irrespective of their block presence) under same ngModel. So, problem again turns down to unique id generation between nested ng-repeats